# ERROR - 'Contact validation failed: con_name: Cast to strin…n_name", con_email: Path `con_email` is required.'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose, material-ui

Please help me to find out the issue. I am developing the "Contact us" page and I have 7 forms to contact 7 different people. I have developed 7 components ("RSform", "RC1form", "RC2form", "RC3form", "RC4form", "RC5form", "RC6form") and all these 7 components have the same structure of the code. For the form submission I have used EmailJS and as you know it's only frontend development and it works well. Now, my issue is not in the form. It's in the left side thing.
[image]

Admin can click on the icon button below the image and do CRUD operations such as add, edit and delete. For this I have developed backend files ("models/Contact.js", routes and controllers) which works well in postman, but not in client side. Admin gets errors as you see in the above or below pictures, when admin click on the "save" button.
[image]

The other thing, I have one database as "contacts" to store all data of 7 different persons. So how to fetch each data separately (image, con_name and con_email)? Because 7 components are called in "index.jsx" component. I am confused.

Following are backend files.

models/Contact.js

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const ContactSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    con_name: {
      type: String,
      required: true, 
    },
    con_email: {
      type: String,
      required: true, 
    },
    image: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: null,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true },
  { typeKey: '$type' }
);

const Contact = mongoose.model("Contact", ContactSchema);
export default Contact;
```

routes/client.js

```
import express from "express";
import {
  //Contacts
  getContacts,
  getContactById,
  saveContact,
  saveContactById,
  updateContact,
  deleteContact,
} from "../controllers/client.js";

const router = express.Router();

//Contacts
router.get("/contacts", getContacts);
router.get("/contacts/:id", getContactById);
router.post("/contacts", saveContact);
router.post("/contacts/:id", saveContactById);
router.patch("/contacts/:id", updateContact);
router.delete("/contacts/:id", deleteContact);

export default router;
```

controllers/client.js

```
//get all contacts *********************************************************************************************

export const getContacts = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const contacts = await Contact.find();
    res.status(200).json(contacts);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};

// get contact by id

export const getContactById = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const contacts = await Contact.findById(req.params.id);
    res.json(contacts);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(404).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};

// add contact

export const saveContact = async (req, res) => {
  const contacts = new Contact(req.body);
  try {
    const insertedContact = await contacts.save();
    res.status(201).json(insertedContact);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};

// add contact by id
export const saveContactById = async (req, res) => {
  const contacts = new Contact(req.body);
  try {
    const insertedContact = await contacts.save();
    res.status(201).json(insertedContact);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};


//update contact

export const updateContact = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const updatedContact = await Contact.updateOne(
      { _id: req.params.id },
      { $set: req.body }
    );
    res.status(200).json(updatedContact);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};

//delete contact

export const deleteContact = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const deletedContact = await Contact.deleteOne({ _id: req.params.id });
    res.status(200).json(deletedContact);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};
```

Following are the frontend files:

scenes/index.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { Grid, Box } from "@mui/material";
import RSform from "./RegionalSuperior";
import RC1form from "./RegionalCoun_1";
import RC2form from "./RegionalCoun_2";
import RC3form from "./RegionalCoun_3";
import RC4form from "./RegionalCoun_4";
import RC5form from "./RegionalCoun_5";
import RC6form from "./RegionalCoun_6";

const ContactForm = () => {
  return (
    <Box>
      <Grid
        container
        direction="column"
        alignItems="center"
        justifyContent="center"
      >
        <Grid item xs={12} md={4} paddingRight={5}>
          <Box sx={{ marginBottom: 2 }}>
            <RSform />
          </Box>
          <Box sx={{ marginBottom: 2 }}>
            <RC1form />
          </Box>
          <Box sx={{ marginBottom: 2 }}>
            <RC2form />
          </Box>
          <Box sx={{ marginBottom: 2 }}>
            <RC3form />
          </Box>
          <Box sx={{ marginBottom: 2 }}>
            <RC4form />
          </Box>
          <Box sx={{ marginBottom: 2 }}>
            <RC5form />
          </Box>
          <Box sx={{ marginBottom: 2 }}>
            <RC6form />
          </Box>
          <br></br>
          <br></br>
          <br></br>
          <br></br>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default ContactForm;
```

scenes/RSform.jsx [all the other components ("RC1form" - "RC6from") are same like the follwing]

```
import { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import emailjs from "emailjs-com";
import { TextField, Button, Typography, Grid, Box } from "@mui/material";
import ImageList from "@mui/material/ImageList";
import ImageListItem from "@mui/material/ImageListItem";
import ImageListItemBar from "@mui/material/ImageListItemBar";
import IconButton from "@mui/material/IconButton";
import InfoIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Info";
import {
  Dialog,
  DialogTitle,
  DialogContent,
  DialogActions,
} from "@mui/material";
import imageUpload from "../../../utils/imageUpload";

const RSform = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [openDialog, setOpenDialog] = useState(false);
  const [editContact, setEditContact] = useState(null);
  const [image, setAddImage] = useState("");
  const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState(null);

  // Function to update a contact
  const updateContact = async (id, con_name, con_email, image) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.patch(
        `http://localhost:5001/client/contacts/${id}`,
        {
          con_name,
          con_email,
          image,
        }
      );
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  };

  // Function to add a new contact
  const saveContact = async (con_name, con_email, image) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        `http://localhost:5001/client/contacts`,
        {
          con_name,
          con_email,
          image,
        }
      );
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  };

  // Function to delete a contact
  const deleteContact = async (id) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.delete(
        `http://localhost:5001/client/contacts/${id}`
      );
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  };

  const itemData = [
    {
      img: image, // Assuming 'image' is defined elsewhere
      title: editContact ? editContact.con_name : "", // Access 'con_name' from 'editContact'
      author: editContact ? editContact.con_email : "", // Access 'con_email' from 'editContact'
    },
    // Add more items as needed
  ];

  const handleOpenDialog = () => {
    setOpenDialog(true);
  };

  const handleCloseDialog = () => {
    setOpenDialog(false);
    setEditContact(null);
  };

  const handleEditContact = (con_name, con_email, image) => {
    setEditContact(con_name, con_email, image);
    handleOpenDialog();
  };

  const handleImageChange = async (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    const url = await imageUpload(file, "contact");
    setAddImage(url);
  };

  const handleSaveContact = async () => {
    try {
      if (editContact && editContact._id) {
        // Update contact
        await updateContact(editContact._id, editContact);
      } else {
        // Add contact
        await saveContact(editContact);
      }
      handleCloseDialog();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error saving contact:", error);
      if (error.response) {
        console.error("Response data:", error.response.data);
      }
      // Handle error
    }
  };

  const handleDeleteContact = async () => {
    try {
      if (editContact) {
        // Delete contact
        await deleteContact(editContact._id);
        handleCloseDialog();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error deleting contact:", error);
      // Handle error
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const templateParams = {
        name,
        email,
        message,
      };

      // Replace 'YOUR_SERVICE_ID' and 'YOUR_TEMPLATE_ID' with your EmailJS service and template IDs
      const response = await emailjs.send(
        "service_51xlzhj",
        "template_la4f9wl",
        templateParams,
        "4hatPMNHGEBnAsuKg" // Replace with your EmailJS user ID
      );

      // Check the response and handle success/failure accordingly
      if (response.status === 200) {
        setName("");
        setEmail("");
        setMessage("");
        alert("Email sent successfully!");
      } else {
        alert("Failed to send email. Please try again later.");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error sending email:", error);
      alert("Failed to send email. Please try again later.");
    }
  };

  return (
    <Grid
      container
      direction="column"
      alignItems="center"
      justifyContent="center"
    >
      <Dialog open={openDialog} onClose={handleCloseDialog}>
        <DialogTitle>
          {editContact ? "Edit Contact" : "Add Contact"}
        </DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          {/* Add form fields for contact data */}
          <TextField
            label="Name"
            value={editContact ? editContact.con_name : ""}
            onChange={(e) =>
              setEditContact({ ...editContact, con_name: e.target.value })
            }
            margin="normal"
            fullWidth
          />
          <TextField
            label="Email"
            value={editContact ? editContact.con_email : ""}
            onChange={(e) =>
              setEditContact({ ...editContact, con_email: e.target.value })
            }
            margin="normal"
            fullWidth
          />
          <div>
            {image && (
              <div>
                <img
                  src={image}
                  alt="contact"
                  style={{ width: "200px", height: "200px" }}
                />
              </div>
            )}
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="file-input" className="file-input-label">
                <strong>Choose Image</strong>
                <input
                  id="file-input"
                  type="file"
                  accept="image/*"
                  onChange={handleImageChange}
                />
                {selectedImage && <p>Selected image: {selectedImage.name}</p>}
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          {/* Add more fields as needed */}
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleCloseDialog}>Cancel</Button>
          <Button onClick={handleSaveContact}>Save</Button>
          <Button onClick={handleDeleteContact}>Delete</Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>

      <Grid item xs={12} md={4}>
        <Box sx={{ p: 2 }} marginTop={10}>
          <Typography variant="h4" align="center" mb={2}>
            Contact Regional Superior
          </Typography>
          <br></br>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Grid container spacing={2}>
              <Grid item xs={12} md={4} marginLeft={15}>
                <Box sx={{ display: "flow", justifyContent: "center" }}>
                  <ImageList sx={{ width: 600, height: 350 }}>
                    {itemData.map((item) => (
                      <ImageListItem key={item.img}>
                        <img src={item.img} alt={item.title} loading="lazy" />
                        <ImageListItemBar
                          title={item.title}
                          subtitle={item.author}
                          actionIcon={
                            <IconButton
                              sx={{ color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.54)" }}
                              aria-label={`info about ${item.title}`}
                              onClick={() => handleEditContact(item)} // Pass the contact data to edit
                            >
                              <InfoIcon />
                            </IconButton>
                          }
                        />
                      </ImageListItem>
                    ))}
                  </ImageList>
                </Box>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
                <TextField
                  fullWidth
                  label="Your Name"
                  value={name}
                  onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                  margin="normal"
                  required
                />
                <TextField
                  fullWidth
                  label="Your Email"
                  value={email}
                  onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
                  margin="normal"
                  required
                  type="email"
                />
                <TextField
                  fullWidth
                  label="Message"
                  value={message}
                  onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
                  margin="normal"
                  required
                  multiline
                  rows={4}
                />
                <Button variant="contained" type="submit" sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
                  Submit
                </Button>
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </form>
        </Box>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default RSform;
```

Please help me to get my task done. I could not find the issue. Help me please.